# ANR during app restart

Tags: android

Precondition:

Android 4.0.3.

Steps to reproduce:

open app, press back key.

Bug was reproduced once.

Is this error a android bug or my app. bug?

```
  "InputDispatcher" prio=10 tid=31 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4165e6c0 self=0x23cfa8
  | sysTid=1916 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=2017576
  | schedstat=( 22339660675 10841338980 166402 ) utm=1041 stm=1192 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41f3e5d8> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$4)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.dumpStackTraces(ActivityManagerService.java:2980)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.dumpStackTraces(ActivityManagerService.java:2958)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.appNotResponding(ActivityManagerService.java:3195)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.keyDispatchingTimedOut(ActivityRecord.java:757)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token.keyDispatchingTimedOut(ActivityRecord.java:243)
  at com.android.server.wm.InputMonitor.notifyANR(InputMonitor.java:108)
  at com.android.server.wm.InputManager$Callbacks.notifyANR(InputManager.java:608)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: ANR is usually caused when you are performing time consuming operations on the main thread we can avoid it by pushing such operations on background thread or by Async Task these operations are generally network based.

Comment: dont check the InputDispatcher thread, check your app's main thread's stack. That is where the actual ANR cause will be known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont check the InputDispatcher thread, check your app's main thread's stack. That is where the actual ANR cause will be known. – nandeesh 2 mins ago

This is a right solution